# The pdf of Chi-squared distribution where X is a Chi-squared distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, chi-squared

Suppose X and Y are independent, zero-mean Gaussian random variables with variances of $$σ_X^2 ,σ_Y^2$$ Let $$Z = X^2 + Y^2 , W = Z^2-Y^2$$

**How do you find the joint pdf of Z and W?**

I found the pdf of Z by scaling the Chi-squared distribution and got $$fz(z) = \frac{1}{2σ_X^2σ_Y^2} exp(-\frac{z}{(σ_X^2σ_Y^2)^2})$$

But I can't find W, or the joint pdf

Comment: Should it read $W=X^2-Y^2$?

Comment: No, it's Z^2 - Y^2. That's the confusing part for me

Comment: So, $W = (X^2+Y^2)^2-Y^2$?

Comment: yes. that's correct